# In Visual Studio 2017 can I use project references on my desktop but file references on a TeamCity build server?

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

I have a Visual Studio project that compiles to a desktop application and the solution it is in references multiple shared libraries.  Each library is in it's own Git repo and is a VS project. When working on my desktop I like to add all of the shared library projects into the VS solution and use project references so I can compile/run/debug all of the shared projects.  This is awkward on our TeamCity build server where I would like a build configuration for each shared library/project and have my application use artifact dependencies to reference the dlls the build server generates.

Is there a way to use project references when on my desktop but file references when on the build server?